# wxpython: closing application does not close the progress bar

Tags: python, wxpython, progress-bar

I have an app that retrieves data from a SQL server. I include a progress bar to show the progress.

However, the problem is that when I try to close the application by clicking the "x" at the top right corner of the application window, the application's main window will close, but the progress bar will continue to run, until all the work with the SQL server is finished.

**I wonder if there is a way to terminate everything when clicking "x".** A sample code (minus the part that does the data retrieval from SQL server) is below:

```
import wx, pyodbc

class App(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, title):
        super(App, self).__init__(parent, title=title, size=(600, 400))
        #-----------------------------------------------------------
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_CLOSE, self.OnExit)  # ADDED 
        #-----------------------------------------------------------
        p = wx.Panel(self)
        nb = wx.Notebook(p)
        self.Panel1 = PanelMaker(nb, 'Foo')               
        nb.AddPage(self.Panel1, "Foo")
        sizer = wx.BoxSizer()
        sizer.Add(nb, 1, wx.EXPAND)
        p.SetSizer(sizer)
        self.Centre()

    #-----------------------------------------------------------
    def OnExit(self, evt):    #ADDED
        self.Destroy()
        #self.Close() #I tried self.Close(), but I could not even 
                      #close the application window when using it.
    #-----------------------------------------------------------
class ProgressBar(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, title="In progress...", size=(300, 90),  style = wx.FRAME_FLOAT_ON_PARENT)        
        GridBagSizer = wx.GridBagSizer()

        self.gauge = wx.Gauge(self, range = 100, size = (-1, 30), style =  wx.GA_HORIZONTAL, name = 'In Progress') 
        self.gauge.SetValue(0)
        txt = wx.StaticText(self, label = 'Hamsters are working very hard to move data', style = wx.ALIGN_CENTER)

        GridBagSizer.Add(self.gauge, pos = (0, 0), span = (1, 1), flag = wx.EXPAND|wx.ALL, border = 15)
        GridBagSizer.Add(txt, pos = (1, 0), span = (1, 1), flag = wx.ALL, border = 15)
        self.SetSizer(GridBagSizer)
        self.Layout()

    def Update(self, step):        
        self.gauge.SetValue(step)
        if step == 100:
            self.Close()

class PanelMaker(wx.Panel):    
    def __init__(self, parent, tool):
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent = parent)
        Panel1Sizer = wx.GridBagSizer(0, 10)

        ProceedButton = wx.Button(self, label = tool, size = (-1, -1))   

        ProceedButton.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnProceedButton)
        Panel1Sizer.Add(ProceedButton, pos = (7, 0), span = (1, 1), flag = wx.EXPAND|wx.LEFT, border = 12)
        Panel1Sizer.Layout()
        self.SetSizer(Panel1Sizer)    

    def OnProceedButton(self, evt):
        Progbar = ProgressBar(self.GetParent())
        Progbar.Show()

        connection = pyodbc.connect(DRIVER = '{SQL Server}',
                                    SERVER = ServerName,
                                    DATABASE = DatabaseName,
                                    Trusted_Connection = True)

        cursor = connection.cursor()

        for i in range(100):
            #retrieve data from the SQL server.......
            wx.Yield()
            Progbar.Update(i+1)

    #Closing SQL connection    
    cursor.close()
    del cursor
    connection.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, bind the close event.

```
self.Bind(wx.EVT_CLOSE, self.OnExit)
```

Also, I don't see you closing the database connection or a `self.Destroy()`

Comment: I made changes based on your suggestion, but still the same thing happens: the main app window can be closed, but the progress bar will still proceed until the SQL process is finished. Can you provided a little more detail or a fuller edit to my sample code? Thanks!

Comment: I would add the closing of the connection code to the OnExit function as well, before the self.Destroy()